# Why is firebase throwing a permission error after sign-out?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In a react-native application, dispatching an action that invokes firebase-auth to sign-out ends in a firebase permission error:

[image]

Here's the method inside the drawer component that dispatches the action:

```
logout = () => {
        this.props
            .logoutUser()
            .then(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err));
    };
```

and here's the `logout` action:

```
export const logoutUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.RESET_APP });
                    console.log('Dispatching types.RESET_APP');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => reject(error.message));
        });
    };
};
```

When executed, the screen reverts back to the login screen as desired. Console logs `Dispatching types.RESET_APP`, and THEN the error above displays.

authStateChanged Listener in my login:

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.LOGIN_USER });
        // listen for change in auth state before signing in
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    console.log('User Credential: ' + JSON.stringify(userCredential));
                    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                        if (user) {
                            console.log('Logged in: ' + user.email);
                            loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user);
                            resolve(user);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Authentication state changed, user object is null...');
                            //resetAuth();
                        }
                    });
                    // No longer need to listen to auth state
                    unsubscribe();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error during Email sign-in: ' + error);
                    loginUserFail(dispatch, error.message);
                });
        });
    };
};
```

auth state observer is unsubscribed in the login function, so whats causing this?

Comment: Because you still have onSnapshot that in not unsubscribe in one of you component.

Comment: @CR7 That sounds like the start of a great answer, especially if you can add some code-samples to it about what the mistake is, and how to fix it.

Comment: @CR7 Yes, on the right track. I was thinking the same, but because of the  `unsubscribe()` described in my edit, im confused. does every single snapshot need to be unsubscribed?

Comment: @Jim yes you should unsubscribe on each of you component, for this issue but also for optimisation

Comment: @CR7 what type of optimization are you referring to

Comment: @Jim optimizing the battery usage and phone memory usage